# Vertical jCarousel with Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, ajax, jcarousel

Can anyone please help me how to implement vertical jCarousel by using ajax.

Comment: Try googling or binging for it first

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this question can be easily found on the first pages of jCarousel docs, but okay, I'll copy it here for you ;)

First of all download jCarousel and add all the sources to your `<head>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/lib/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/lib/jquery.jcarousel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/skin/skin.css" />
```

Then in the place where you want your carousel put this code.

```
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-name">
   <!-- The content goes in here -->
</ul>
```

Then add js code to initialize your carousel.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        // Carousel gonna be vertical
        vertical : true,
        // AJAX callback
        itemLoadCallback: itemLoadCallbackFunction
    });
});
</script>
```

Then you need to create itemLoadCallBackFunction to actually load new items into carousel dynamically. Basicly once you get some item with index `i` you just insert it to carousel with `carousel.add(i, item)`.

UPD:

[Here](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_ajax_php.html) is an example with PHP script inside, you can get some inspiration from there.